# open vim file in new unix terminal

Tags: vim, vi

How to open existing vim file from unix shell (bash) in new terminal (not in same/new tab of existing terminal) on local machine ?

Also is there any way to split file on new terminal (not in same/new tab of existing terminal) from inside vim ?

Answer (score 1):

How to open a new terminal is platform dependent; This doesn't really have a whole lot to do with vim itself.

For example, if you're using GNOME you could do this by running `gnome-terminal -e "vim $filename" & disown`. Look up the documentation for the terminal emulator you're using to find out how to launch a new terminal and execute commands in it.

Another (IMHO much better) solution is to simply use GVim for situations like these, unless you have a very good reason to run vim in the terminal (if you're running this over ssh this won't work anyway, in that case you're better off using a terminal multiplexer like screen or tmux).

---

PS: bash isn't a terminal (emulator); bash is a shell. If you just run a new instance of bash it'll run in the same terminal, which is not what you want here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
vim [your file]
```

If this isn't working for you, make sure you have it installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

If you're already IN `vim` do

```
:edit [your file]
```

Comment: How does that open it in a new terminal?

Comment: This won't open a new terminal window.